# Surprisingly many network interfaces on macOS: are these legitimate?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, vpn

`ifconfig` reveals a surprisingly long list of network interfaces on my MacBook, which is running macOS High Sierra (10.13.6): `lo0`, `gif0`, `stf0`, `XHC20`, `en0`, `p2p0`, `awdl0`, `en1`, `en2`, `bridge0`, `utun0`.

There is an F5 VPN client installed, but I've rebooted the MacBook since the last VPN connection.

Are all of these network interfaces legitimate or is this something I should worry about?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These are perfectly normal.

- `lo` is the loopback interface
- `en0` and `en1` are your hardware interfaces (usually Ethernet and WiFi)
- `p2p0` is a point to point link (usually VPN)
- `stf0` is a "six to four"  interface (IPv6 to IPv4)
- `gif01` is a software interface
- `bridge0` is a software bridge between other interfaces
- `utun0` is used for "Back to My Mac"
- `XHC20` is a USB network interface
- `awdl0` is Apple Wireless Direct Link (Bluetooth) to iOS devices

In my personal setup I have 2 addtional `en` interfaces (`en2` and `en3`), as well as two software interfaces specific to VirtualBox, `vboxnet0` and `vboxnet1`.  Other virtualization applications like VMware, Parallels, and Docker will create their own interfaces as will VPN clients.

Comment: utun is the tunnel interface driver, p2p is Apple’s custom WiFi-Direct (used by things like personal hotspot in place of normal WiFi in some phases, and AirDrop and other custom additions etc). utun is used by OpenVPN and IKEv2 for example

Comment: please can you help with this question ?https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343072/mac-i-cant-use-direct-ip-192-168-0-instead-keep-getting-192-168-1

Comment: where is the reference or define for XHC0, XHC1, XHC20, VHC128?

Comment: This answer is amazing. I think awdl0 now floats over WiFi for bonjour and also loops in Bluetooth but I can not be sure. Also utun0 / utun1 seem to proliferate even if you don’t have VPN software or profiles installed.

Comment: @Allan "Back to My Mac" is deprecated yet ifconfig shows Catalina (10.15.6)  has created 5 `utun` interfaces `utun0` - `utun4`. Is there a way to find what process is creating these or what they are for?

Comment: @John - BTM is just rebanded as "Find My..." it's the same service, just a different name.

Comment: @Allan Thanks. That's one of them. Do you know what creates the other four `utun` interfaces? Or better yet, can show me how to find what creates them using command line arguments.

Comment: @John `utun` interfaces can also be created by other services (i.e. home sharing, icloud, etc.)   VPN software can/will also use these interfaces.

Comment: I am quite sure that p2p0 is for WiFi Direct and not for VPN?

Comment: i would also like to know how these network interfaces are turning on..any suggestions?

Comment: More than likely, they are created sometime during boot and autoactivated when the userland environment is initialized