# Web access blocked but ping and DNS is fine ( on all interfaces )

Tags: network, internet, ventura

I am now looking after someone else's Mac, running Ventura 13.4.  Everything was fine up until last Friday.  And then it suddenly lost "most" Internet connectivity.

To be precise, Zoom, virus scanner updates, Safari, etc. does not work.  I cannot go anywhere.

The computer previously had access to our company's LAN and WiFi.  Both still work -- I get green lights in the System Settings.  But that's all -- only confirmation in the system settings that they are connected.  I then disabled both and tried to tether it through my phone.  Again, I get connected, but none of the above applications work -- I cannot access anything.

I also tried to go to `www.google.com` using `curl` and I get a "Couldn't connect to server".  Repeating this with its IP address doesn't work as well.

So, I think this safely eliminates any problem with our company's network...

What does work on all 3 (WiFi, LAN, and tethering) is I can open up a terminal and `ping`.  In fact, I can ping `www.google.com` by domain name, which gets translated to its IP address with no problems.

I browsed through the system's log files in `/var/log` and nothing caught my eye, though I don't know what I'm looking for.

I don't have much Mac experience, but I do have Linux experience.  I don't believe I've seen something like this before.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

Edit 1:

I was unable to run `ipconfig getpacket en0` because nothing was returned.  However, I ran `ifconfig` and noticed two interfaces were "active" (`en0` was inactive).  `en1` and `awdl0` were the only two out of 23 that are active.  With `en1`, I get:

```
% ipconfig getpacket en1 | grep -i "router\|domain\|ciaddr"
ciaddr = 0.0.0.0
yiaddr = 10.206.233.147
router (ip_mult): {10.206.128.1}
domain_name_server (ip_mult): {10.255.250.1, 10.255.250.2}
domain_name (string): XXX.ac.uk
```

(Nothing gets returned with `awdl0`.)

Edit 2:

The computer in question has a LAN cable that is currently unplugged.  Presumably, that is `en0`.

Edit 3:

```
% host bing.com            
bing.com has address 204.79.197.200
bing.com has address 13.107.21.200
bing.com has IPv6 address 2620:1ec:c11::200
bing.com mail is handled by 10 bing-com.mail.protection.outlook.com.

% ping 204.79.197.200
PING 204.79.197.200 (204.79.197.200): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 204.79.197.200: icmp_seq=0 ttl=116 time=9.737 ms
64 bytes from 204.79.197.200: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=6.555 ms
64 bytes from 204.79.197.200: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=9.262 ms
64 bytes from 204.79.197.200: icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=10.751 ms
^C
--- 204.79.197.200 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 6.555/9.076/10.751/1.552 ms

% traceroute 204.79.197.200
traceroute to 204.79.197.200 (204.79.197.200), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.206.128.2 (10.206.128.2)  9.470 ms  3.529 ms  3.309 ms
 2  10.3.4.46 (10.3.4.46)  4.026 ms  3.421 ms  3.198 ms
 3  10.3.1.53 (10.3.1.53)  4.545 ms  3.974 ms  3.930 ms
 4  10.3.2.9 (10.3.2.9)  4.893 ms  5.478 ms  4.011 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
^C

% curl 204.79.197.200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 204.79.197.200 port 80 after 10 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: Let's start with some basic info.  Issue the command `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep -i "router\|domain\|ciaddr"` Paste that with an [edit] to your question.  You can send it directly to your clipboard by piping the output with `| pbcopy` at the end of the command.  (And no, it's not a typo, the command is `ipconfig` with a "P")

Comment: Thanks @Allan!  I've updated the question using the command you suggested.  I don't know what the output means, but something seems wrong with `ciaddr`...  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  `ciaddr` is "Client IP Address." Seeing that yours is coming back empty, rerun and add `\|yiaddr` before the last quote.  Both of these should be your assigned address (from DHCP) and are usually the same, but let's check to make sure.

Comment: `awdl0` is a [Bluetooth connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332194/119271) so unless you're internet sharing using your phone via BT, there's no worry there.

Comment: You're not behind a firewall? Did you say you were on the "company LAN?"

Comment: Thanks @Allan for the prompt response!  I just stumbled on something now and was trying to figure it out before writing a follow-up comment.  I'm actually at a university and yes...we should be behind a firewall...  Does what I just output imply I'm not?  Under Network | Filters, I found a our VPN which is of type "Content Filter".  Its Status is enabled with a yellow circle.  How do I remove that?  Our IT Support is busy, but one of the things they advised me before I came here was to uninstall the VPN.  I did that.  But I'm surprised this filter is still here.  I can't right-click it...

Comment: @Allan And thanks for the link to the list of interfaces!  The list was helpful!

Comment: For a second I thought you weren’t, 10.2xx.xxx.xxx isn’t common so I misread it. You DO have a private IP. All good there.  The next thing to try is to see if you DNS server resolved.  Type `host bing.com` (or whatever domain you like).  Then, try pinging the IP.  If it fails, do `traceroute IP`.  Post the results like last time

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help me, @Allan!  I've added the outputs, including a `curl` run right after.  Doesn't make sense to me.  I'm beginning to wonder if it's a problem with (1) that "Content Filter" I mentioned above, from a VPN that I had just removed or (2) my organisation is somehow blocking my outbound access -- allowing `ping` but not web access.  I'm asking the VPN's forum for some advice and I'm thinking of taking the output above and asking my organisation.  I'll follow-up here if I hear something from that.  I'm not sure if you or someone else sees an issue on my side?

Comment: Please, clarify your original question with a uniq connection to the Internet, preferably through an Ethernet cable. Next which VPN are you using? How is it configured?

Comment: Thanks @dan!  I will do that as soon as I return to the office after the weekend.  The VPN is a company VPN, using GlobalProtect.  It was installed using its installation program.  I've ran the uninstallation program, but that aforementioned "Content Filter" remains.  I have also Googled about GP and the discussion boards I've seen have given less than flattering reviews about it.  Anyway, our IT Support advised me to run the `uninstall_gp.sh` script, but haven't responded to me further when that didn't work.

Comment: In your tracerote, it appears things drop around hop 5 which is *still* inside your organization.   Do you have the ability to tether or use your phone as a hot spot just to test?  If you do that and can browse properly, you’ve eliminated your Mac from the equation and have something to bring to your Uni’s network admins.

Comment: @Allan, GlobalProtect will route any kind of connection on top of a direct connection to the VPN server which is the PaloAlto firewall of the company, and the connection will be authenticated through 802.1X and an internal Radius server.

Comment: This other question:
https://superuser.com/questions/770414/mac-cannot-browse-ping-works-fine
doesn't contain any analysis and useful solution, forget it.
I even advise you to remove your reference to this useless other question.

Comment: If you uninstall GlobalProtect on your Mac, you will loose any access to your company network, both locally and toward the public Internet. Your Mac won't get any IP inside your company network.
But on the other hand, you will be able to connect to the Internet through your iPhone.
Then you will be able to conclude that there was a recent filtering update on your PaloAlto firewall and this blocked all forms of `https:` ( ak 443/tcp ) connection.

Comment: Thank you @Allan for the follow-up!  I did notice the drop after 5 hops but I saw the same thing on another (Linux-based) computer here, whose Internet access is fine.  So, I thought maybe that was "ok".  I did try to tether to my phone, and as mentioned in my original question, that didn't work as well.  Thanks to your questions, I've collected enough information to pass to my organisation's IT people.  The Mac is official company equipment, so they should help; but since they're busy, I thought I could collect some information to move things along. I'll update with what they say.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @dan!  For reasons I don't understand, our organisation's IT people asked me to uninstall GlobalProtect.  But, as I said, I had trid to tether to my phone and that didn't work.  So, I *think* GlobalProtect's uninstall was incomplete and left something behind.  GP was required by my organisation, so if this is true, then maybe I need to bug them to help me undo it.  I will edit my question to remove the link to `superuser.com`.  It was useless...but it was all I could find.  Thank you!

Comment: @Allan Thank you for all your help!  The information you helped me gather was enough for me to escalate up to our organisation's IT department.  In fact, I sent them this page's link so that they don't waste any time.  In the end...they gave up.  They decided to wipe the hard disk and re-install the OS!  Yes, they tried all the steps that have worked with other computers in the organisation.  Not surprisingly, now, it's fine...  They think the cause was some organisation network changes that week. Thank you both; it didn't solve my problem directly, but you helped me get their attention!

Comment: @dan (See above comment -- sorry, I can only notify one person at a time.)  Thank you both for your time!!

Comment: To help everyone, you should add to your OQ that you are on a company firewalled network with a PaloAlto, and that your company security admins installed GlobalProtect on your Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description of your problem it is a typical GlobalProtect VPN filtering misbehaving, either because of an error at the filtering on the PaloAlto firewall of your company or within the macOS client.

For anyone seeing the same problem:

- ping is OK, DNS is OK,
- http/https through any physical interface ( Ethernet, Wi-Fi, USB toward an iPhone…) is blocked,

the cleanest solution is to completly uninstall GlobalProtect:
[uninstall GlobalProtect on macOS](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-1/globalprotect-app-user-guide/globalprotect-app-for-mac/uninstall-the-globalprotect-app-for-mac)
and next to report the problem to the security admins of your company for them to test, analyze and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Your description is fairly accurate.  I didn't know it was "typical" for GlobalProtect.  Obviously, I didn't choose them but looking online, it seems some people aren't happy with it.

Comment: This has been a professionnal nightmare for me. Made more damage than cyber-attacks. But a firewall with one of the sexiest interface as long as you don't touch it too often.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few troubleshooting steps you can try:

1. Clear DNS cache: Open the Terminal and enter the command `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` to clear the DNS cache. This can help resolve any potential DNS-related issues.
2. Reset network settings: Go to "System Preferences" > "Network" and select the active network connection (e.g., Wi-Fi or Ethernet). Click the minus (-) button to remove it, then click the plus (+) button to add it back. This will reset the network settings for that connection.
3. Check proxy settings: In "System Preferences," go to "Network" and select the active network connection. Click on "Advanced" and navigate to the "Proxies" tab. Ensure that no proxy settings are enabled unless required by your network configuration.
4. Reset TCP/IP stack: Open the Terminal and enter the following commands one by one:

   - `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`
   - `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
   - `sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper`
   - `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`
5. Disable firewall and security software temporarily: Temporarily disable any firewall or security software you have installed and check if that resolves the issue. Remember to re-enable them afterward for security purposes.
6. Verify date and time settings: Ensure that the date and time settings on your MacBook are accurate. Incorrect date and time settings can sometimes cause issues with secure connections.

Comment: There is no "System Preferences" in macOS Ventura. Also, if you copy answers from somewhere else, please link back to the source for reference.

Comment: @nohillside Thank you for pointing this out so that I don't keep looking...  macOS does change from version to version slightly...